# Xamarin.Forms binding using class from different assembly

Tags: ios, mvvm, xamarin.forms, .net-assembly

I’m trying to set up a Xamarin.Forms solution using the three assemblies „Model“, „ViewModel“ and „View“ to separate my code according to MVVM style like i did often before in Windows WPF apps.

The iOS and Android bootstrapper projects have both references to each of the three assemblies View-Assembly has a reference to ViewModel and Model, ViewModel only references Model.

I added a simple „MainPage“ in View-Assembly and the matching „MainViewModel“ in ViewModel-Assembly.
Everything compiles fine and the Xamarin.Forms-Previewer in Visual Studio shows me a preview where a Label-Text is shown via binding to the ViewModel.

On Android simulator the app works as expected. 
On iOS it crashes when it tries to show the Page.

I guess this has a lot to do with: iOS is using ahead of time compiling. Or maybe i do something wrong in defining the xmlns tag in xaml.

Unhandled Exception:
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 8:10. 
Type vm:MainPageViewModel not found in
xmlns clr-namespace:MyApp3.ViewModel;assembly=MyApp3.ViewModel

Code:

```
namespace MyApp3.ViewModel
{
    public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public string MyText { get; set; } = "Some Text";
    }
}
```

And Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp3"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp3.ViewModel;assembly=MyApp3.ViewModel"
             x:Class="MyApp3.View.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:MainPageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding MyText}"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Do i just miss some hidden setting or is this a limitation so i have to keep my code inside one Assembly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, check the names.
Check if the assembly name of view models is named MyApp3.ViewModel (check it in the properties of the project).